# Geometric estimate of a function

Tags: integration, analysis, estimation

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function such that $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)>0$ on $[1, \infty)$. Then  I want to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)-\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\ dx- \frac{f(n)}{2} - \frac{f(1)}{2} \leq \frac{f'(n)}{4}$$
for all natural numbers $n$. However, I cannot get any motivation of how the term $\frac{f'(n)}{4}$ appears in this estimate...Could anyone please help me?

Comment: tiny error in the formula, where is d$x$

Comment: I just omitted it because this symbol is often omitted.